# Can't run Pulse Secure on Ubuntu 19.04 because libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0 is missing

Tags: 19.04

Is there a way to solve this?

```
$ /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It sounds as though you updated from an earlier version of Ubuntu?  What application are you trying to run.

Comment: right I upgraded from 18.10 trying to run Pulse Secure a VPN client

Comment: From their website, they don't officially support anything over 18.04, however I did see a tech note there indicating that there was a way to run it on 18.10.  You may need to contact them for support [https://www-prev.pulsesecure.net/download/techpubs/current/1383/pulse-client/pulse-secure-client-desktop/9.0rx/ps-pulse-9.0r2-supportedplatforms.pdf](https://www-prev.pulsesecure.net/download/techpubs/current/1383/pulse-client/pulse-secure-client-desktop/9.0rx/ps-pulse-9.0r2-supportedplatforms.pdf)

Comment: Try this `wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb; sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Thanks I then get: ```dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (= 2.4.11-4); however:
  Package libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~); however:
  Package libicu60 is not installed.```

Comment: ok got it to work by installing https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html and ```wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb; sudo apt install -f
``` and then the one you mentioned

Comment: You might to like that as an answer :)

Comment: I upvoted the comment is that what you meant? Or there is another way? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No, I  mean post what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 42):

Ubuntu 19.04 is not a supported platform for Pulse Secure.
You may get it to work by following the instructions below without installing dependencies with the package manager.
Note: Use carefully && caution with your own risk.

- As **root user**, run:

  ```
  dpkg -i pulse-9.0.R3.x86_64.deb
  cd /usr/local/pulse/
  ```
- Allow installation for 19.04 (or 19.10 / 20.04 / 20.10 / 21.04) by sed ( or manually in line 279 in PulseClient_x86_64.sh). In below is it for 19.04/19.10.

  ```
  sed -i "s/UBUNTU_VER\ \=\ 18\ \]/& \|\|\ [\ \$UBUNTU_VER\ \=\ 19 \]/" PulseClient_x86_64.sh
  ```
- May not needed. At least it will fail with packages which not found.

  ```
  ./PulseClient_x86_64.sh install_dependency_packages
  ```
- Lets make debs and extra folders:

  ```
  mkdir /usr/local/pulse/extra
  mkdir /usr/local/pulse/debs
  ```
- Download below packages from archice.ubuntu.com to
  /usr/local/pulse/debs:

  ```
  cd /usr/local/pulse/debs
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  ```
- Extract *.deb files on /usr/local/pulse/extra

  ```
  cd /usr/local/pulse/extra
  dpkg -x /usr/local/pulse/debs/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb .
  dpkg -x /usr/local/pulse/debs/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb .
  dpkg -x /usr/local/pulse/debs/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb .
  ```
- Which to normal user and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in command line:

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
  ```
- On Ubuntu 20.04 (and after) you might need to install libenchant.so.1:

  sudo apt-get install libenchant1c2a
- On Ubuntu 21.04 you will need to install libenchant1c2a manually:

  ```
  cd /usr/local/pulse/debs
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/enchant/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.4_amd64.deb
  cd /usr/local/pulse/extra/
  dpkg -x /usr/local/pulse/debs/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.4_amd64.deb .
  ```
- As normal user, run pulse secure GUI on command line:

  ```
  /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
  ```

Now you should able to see pulseUI and continue with it.
Note: For troubleshooting purpose, you can use ldd command to check which libraries are needed, like: `ldd /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi`

If your organization use MFA, you might face issue with 9.1R11 version:
https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Embeded-browser-MFA-login-failure-or-crash-after-login/td-p/45186

Comment: Note, if your IT department provided an older version of the Pulse client, you may need the i386 versions of packages mentioned here. Just substitute i386 instead of amd64 in all the URLs and commands listed here. Worked for me with version 5.3r2.0-b853 .

Comment: This worked like gold at my end, huge thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me after copying and pasting each line, line-by-line. Still getting :
error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I had to hand edit the PulseClient_x86_64.sh file to include v 19. If anyone is interested, I can upload the file with its edits.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: work like a charm! do you guys know how to run it from the icon launcher?

Comment: works on 20.04 (change UBUNTU_VER to 20 in the sed line)

Comment: For Ubuntu 20, see this thread in the Pulse Secure Community: https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Desktop-Clients/pulseUi-doesn-t-work-in-ubuntu-20-04/td-p/42721

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 you will also need to run this command: sudo apt-get install libenchant1c2a

Comment: Great guide. Thanks. Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work when you try to run pulseUI from menu under gnome/wayland. Better add it to /etc/ld.so.conf

Answer (score 12):

On Ubuntu 19.10 (amd64), the following worked for me:

1. Download [libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0), [libwebkitgtk-1.0-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0),
   and [libicu60](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libicu60) corresponding to your architecture (mine was amd64).
2. Install them with `sudo dpkg -i libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb; sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It coincides with [this thread](https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Desktop-Clients/Does-pulseUi-work-in-ubuntu-19/td-p/40538) from the Pulse Secure community.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use Pulse Secure only as a client to connect to a VPN, you can use open connect. Here I go into detail, step by step.

1. **Install the package**

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openconnect
   ```
2. **Install certificates**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
   sudo update-ca-certificates
   ```
3. **Connect**

   ```
   sudo openconnect --protocol = nc vpn.example.com
   ```

References:

http://www.yorku.ca/computing/download/ps-pulse-9.0r1-linux-quickstart-guide.pdf
https://websiteforstudents.com/install-openconnect-ssl-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-04/

Comment: Tried to get PulseClient to work on Ubuntu for at least two hours: failing all the time. Tried openconnect: connected instantly! Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, here is the link with all the packages: https://www.mediafire.com/file/d2atf7q94bfhx8u/PulseUI-Ubuntu19.04-Dep.zip/file

Answer (score 4):

Please forgive the fact that this is an answer and not a comment.  I signed up just to help out on this problem.  To piggyback off what @jacke posted above.  Follow his guide first!

If you notice that your Pulse Icon no longer works from the launcher do the following:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/applications/pulseUi.desktop
```

Edit the Exec line to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
```

Comment: This was almost right for me on Kubuntu 19.10. I had to additionally add /usr/local/pulse/ to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH too, like so my Exec looks like `Exec=/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/pulse:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
`

Comment: this not work for me, the click on the icon doesn't open the app.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was as simple as installing the Pulse deb then running:

```
sudo /usr/local/pulse/PulseClient_x86_64.sh install_dependency_packages
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Comment: This worked for me, only needed the first command, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What's given in @Jacke's answer of 2019.05.13 works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 as well, except I couldn't get functional on my system the simple version change via `sed` in `PulseClient_x86_64.sh`. This is not least for reasons I describe in my Gist at https://gist.github.com/DannyQuah/44df50362677ce7eb2c6fe1546dbef72. Also, I didn't want to confound my 20.04 repositories with 18.04 ones (which some other proposals I've seen elsewhere seemed to suggest). So the `pulse/extra` and `pulse/debs` solution here worked great for me.

To run from the icon launcher, as asked by some above, I navigated to `/usr/share/applications` and edited `pulseUi.desktop` there so its `Exec` matched what you've got above:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
```

Thanks for the solution, @Jacke.

I've also described what I did in greater detail in my Gist at https://gist.github.com/DannyQuah/44df50362677ce7eb2c6fe1546dbef72.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message on reboot, then you may need to reexport $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or add this line to your `.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/pulse/extra/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/;
```