# Ubuntu 22.04 install libenchant1c2a for Pulse Secure

Tags: dependencies, 22.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm struggling to install Pulse Secure.

For installation, I use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142879/1474860)

But got the error:

`./pulseUi: error while loading shared libraries: libenchant.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

As I understand I need `libenchant1c2a`, but I can't install it.
What I did:

```
user@server:~$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/enchant/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.4_amd64.deb
```

Error:

```
--2022-05-23 17:12:49--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/enchant/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.4_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 185.125.190.39, 91.189.91.38, 185.125.190.36, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|185.125.190.39|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-05-23 17:12:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Could you help me?

Comment: "*I can't install it*" is vague. Maybe your command is wrong. Maybe your package name is wrong. Maybe lots of possibilities. The question may be answerable if it includes the complete input and output of what happens when you try to install libenchant.

Comment: @user535733, thank you for your response! I clarify the question.

Comment: `libenchant` has been removed from new Ubuntu version and replaced by `libenchant2`.

Comment: Looks like you are making two common mistakes. 1) You are using wget and dpkg -- that's the hard way. It's much easier to simply use apt, which will automatically solve versions and dependencies for you: `sudo apt install libenchant1c2a` or similar based upon the actual package name for your release of Ubuntu. 2) Becasue of #1, you are specifying a version that's not in the Ubuntu repositories -- that's why you are getting a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks! But I have already had libenchant-2-2, but Pulse does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use Pulse Secure in 22.04 but you'll need manually install some 20.04 packages, try this:

```
wget http://uz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/enchant/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.4_amd64.deb
```

I also had to downgrade package libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0 to a previous release:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.18.5-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.18.5-1_amd64.deb
apt-mark hold libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64
```

Finally, i also had to run the command as root, as running it as a regular user stopped working for me in 22.04.

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Pilot6 in the comments above libenchant has been replaced with libenchant2 found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libenchant-2-dev).
Try installing it with the command:
`sudo apt-get install -y libenchant-2-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I’am able to install pulse secure on Ubuntu 22.04 without problem or required dependencies.
-pulse secure version 9.1 r13.0

I’ve uploaded at this link to share
https://file.io/wP7fShV1o4CZ

Filename: ps-pulse-linux-9.1r13.0-b11723-64bit-installer.deb

Comment: Pulse (the company) should just allow everyone to download the client from their website for free. They already made money selling the pulse server software